# NSOpenPanel does not allow to open app bundle

Tags: macos, swift

i really tried everything now, but i can not manage to get the NSOpenPanel to allow selecting an app bundle. I need it to be possible in my Application, to let the user select a path to an Application bundle. My code looks like this:

```
      var fileDialog:NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()

    fileDialog.prompt = "Select App Bundle"
    fileDialog.canChooseDirectories = false
    fileDialog.canChooseFiles = false
    fileDialog.allowedFileTypes = ["app","APP"]
    fileDialog.treatsFilePackagesAsDirectories = false

    if(fileDialog.runModal() == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
        bundlePath?.setValue(fileDialog.URL?.absoluteString!)
    }
```

Everything else is working as expected but all Application bundles are greyed out and are not selectable. I also tried to set treatsFilePackagesAsDirectories to true. Then i can select them but they will just open in NSOpenPanel and show the contents instead of selecting the path.

Maybe anyone here has a hint for me ?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing `canChooseDirectories` and `treatsFilePackagesAsDirectories` to true:

```
fileDialog.canChooseDirectories = true
fileDialog.treatsFilePackagesAsDirectories = true
```

Comment: I thought that i already did try that but obviously i did not. Thanks for the hint. It seems to be working.